# entity framework 5 transaction doesn't commit

Tags: entity-framework, transactionscope

I don't understand what is wrong with this transction

In case of error the rollback is ok
but the commit never happens 
as the transaction was already interrupted...

What is wrong here?
Thanks!

```
  try
           {


               using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
               {

                   //insert dati swap nella tabella PAPER_OPERATION
                   context.PAPER_OPERATION.Add(op_paper);

                   context.SaveChanges();
                   //si richiama la sp incaricata di effettuare un post processing sui dati dello swap
                   context.SP_PAPER_OPERATION_RUN(op_paper.ID_OPERAZIONE);

                   //per quanto riguarda la prezzatura la prima volta in cui lo swap viene inserito si tratta di un inserimento ex novo di righe nella tabella PRICING_PERIOD
                   //e a seguire nella tabella R_PAPER_OPERATION_PRICING_PERIOD
                   foreach (var pp_buy_to_insert in list_pp_buy)
                   {
                       context.PRICING_PERIOD.Add(pp_buy_to_insert);
                       context.SaveChanges();
                       R_PAPER_OPERATION_PRICING_PERIOD r_oppaper_pp_buy = new R_PAPER_OPERATION_PRICING_PERIOD();
                       r_oppaper_pp_buy.ID_PRICING_PERIOD = pp_buy_to_insert.ID_PRICING_PERIOD;
                       r_oppaper_pp_buy.ID_PREZZATURA_PAPER = Convert.ToString(op_paper.ID_OPERAZIONE) + 'B';
                       context.R_PAPER_OPERATION_PRICING_PERIOD.Add(r_oppaper_pp_buy);
                       context.SaveChanges();
                   }
               id_inserted = op_paper.ID_OPERAZIONE;



                scope.Complete();
               }

                var parameter = new
                {
                    INSERTED_ID = id_inserted
                };


                return Json(parameter, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                                }
```

Comment: You could possibly help yourself if you wouldn't catch away the exception and inspect it instead. Or doesn't your code enter the catch block?

Comment: What error/exception are you encountering?

Comment: {"The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction."}